# Encrypt data with RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, padding, ecb

I have to encrypt the generated symmetric key (AES-256-CBC) with asymmetric encryption in PHP. I got a public certificate (CER file) I should use.
I try to do it like this:

```
$fp = fopen('publickey.cer', 'r');
$pub_key = fread($fp, filesize('publickey.cer'));
fclose($fp);

openssl_public_encrypt($enc, $final, $pub_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

where $enc is my symmetric key

I'm receiving output ($final) which is incorrect.

The working code in Java that works fine looks like this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding") ;
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, x509Certificate.getPublicKey());
return cipher.doFinal(bytes) ;
```

How to transform it into PHP?

Comment: You need to extract the public key from the certificate - just use [openssl_csr_get_public_key](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-csr-get-public-key.php)

Comment: Can you provide a working example ? PHP.NET doesn't have any example thats work for me.

Comment: Place this line: $pub_key = openssl_csr_get_public_key($pub_key); **before** you encrypt ("openssl_public_encrypt")

Comment: It doesn't work right.

My code is:
$fp = fopen('publickey.cer', 'r');
$pub_key = fread($fp, filesize('publickey.cer'));
fclose($fp);

$pub_key = openssl_csr_get_public_key($pub_key);
openssl_public_encrypt($enc, $final1, $pub_key);

I getting error:
Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) for this & refer [PHP RSA examples](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html).

Load library using your uploaded file path & initiate class:

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
```

Encryption:
You can use encryption mode as `PKCS1Padding` or `OAEP`.

```
$public_key="";
$plaintext = 'Hello world'; //string to encrypt

$rsa->loadKey($public_key); 
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1); //PKCS1Padding
//$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP); //OAEP

$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
```

Decryption :

```
$private_key="";

$rsa->loadKey($private_key); // private key
$text = $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
```